# XMLHttpRequest cannot load on same domain

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/scripts/php/sendDispatch.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is on the same domain not separate domains. All the "Possible Duplicates" have been dealing with questions that have had separate domains.

I am getting this error in Chrome.  My understanding is that this type of thing usually happens when trying to access files on another domain. What could be wrong?

Ajax:

```
 var frm = $('#dispatchForm');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                notif({
                type: "success",
                msg: "<b>Success: </b>Your request has been submitted.",
                position: "center",
                width: 500,
                height: 60,
                autohide: false
            });
                $(frm)[0].reset();
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: remove `www` from the request, or put some logic in to build the link based on the subdomain

Comment: Not a possible duplicate as I am not accessing another domain it is on the same domain. It's not even on a subdomain.

Comment: Removing `www` did the trick. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 0):

To be the Same Origin the *port*, *hostname* and *scheme* must match.

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are not the same hostname, even if one is a subdomain of the other.

---

It is generally considered wise to pick one of `www.example.com` and `example.com` to be the canonical name for your site, and to redirect all requests from the non-canonical one to the canonical one.

This can be coupled with *relative* URIs to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the answer here, so you can mark as correct if it fixed for you.. As others indicated, the `www` does not match the non-www:

> remove www from the request, or put some logic in to build the link based on the subdomain